# Sharepoint 2013 web app doesnt work

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I installed sp 2013 recently. Central Admin works fine but sharepoint 80 or any other web app doesnt work.

> Sorry, something went wrong  An unexpected error has occurred. 
>   Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: a9dd9e9d-dfed-e042-5749-0c2119b2c735
>
> Date and Time: 8/30/2016 5:40:14 PM

Found the following errors in event

> Application Server Administration job failed for service instance
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance
>   (aa94f953-3fba-4584-836b-25e610bb9776).
>
> Reason: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Technical Support Details:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated
>   cryptographic algorithms.    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean
>   isAdministrationServiceJob)

---

### Event 2548 (SharePoint Server Search) of severity 'Error' occurred 1678 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID
>   83ef2d7b-6df8-4271-9032-6f16b1ee6a33) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.
>
> ----- Failure trying to synch web application 3950044e-2503-4814-b6fe-4e100762dc08, ContentDB
>   93fcd9a5-2c46-4ff2-881b-1ed561359f34  Exception message was
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 55d39d7c-ea7f-49f9-8763-17c12b9bf319    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType
>   logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState, SyncType
>   syncType, WSSSyncUsageEntry usage, String[]
>   excludedAccountsRegexStrings)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

Comment: could you please run the following powershell on the server and share the ULS logs here Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\Farmlogs.log" -Correlation "a9dd9e9d-dfed-e042-5749-0c2119b2c735"